# Include session in HTTP POST header

Tags: python, session, cookies, http-post

I need to upload a JSON to an API using Python. I have a session header to add to the POST request for authorizing the request. The session is the following format:

session=value=

I have been trying to add it as a header in the python urllib2 library however the API is still giving me a 401 Unauthorized. So far, I'm doing like this:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
req.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'session=value=')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, data=json.dump(data))
```

I have been reading the urllib2 documentation and also the http cookies and I couldn't find a clear way to send this cookie through the headers. Could anybody please give a light here on how to do it?
Unfortunately, for privacy issues, I cannot show the url and the cookie.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should use `Cookie` not `Set-Cokkie`. Others are fine

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
req.add_header('Cookie', 'session=value=')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, data=json.dump(data))
```

When Server response, it uses `Set-Cookie` to persist a cookie in client, when client want to callback, it just use `Cookie` as header.

Comment: Using Cookie gives me the same 401 response.

Comment: You can check the headers using Chrome Debugger tools (F12) during the requests. and use  Network -> copy as curl to see what exactly client pass to server

Comment: Actually, I found out that the api used a different Cookie for keeping the session. req.add_header('Session-Id', 'value') solved the problem. It wouldn't need a question at stackoverflow.